# How to set Transaction Isolation level for a single kodo query?

Tags: java, jdo, kodo

We have been facing deadlocks in some queries(select queries causing deadlocked update queries). By default kodo READS_COMMITTED,which is okay for update queries. I know that we can set this property at  application level :

```
kodo.jdbc.TransactionIsolation: read-uncommitted
```

But in my case, I just want to specify the transaction isolation on a single kodo query.
Is that possible? I am pretty new to kodo, so any help/comments any highly appreciated.

Comment: Using JDO or JPA ? JDO(2.2) allows Transaction.setIsolationLevel. I doubt that Kodo supports JDO 2.2 though, but DataNucleus JDO does.

Comment: We are using kodo-jdo 3.4.0 and jdo 1.0.2 and we are not upgrading it any time soon. I guess we are stuck then..??

Answer (score 0):

Using the documentation of Kodo with JDO:

> Kodo provides explicit APIs to lock objects and to retrieve their
>   current lock level.
>   The Kodo JDO KodoPersistenceManager exposes the following methods to
>   lock objects explicitly

You have the next methods of locking a object:

```
public void lockPersistent (Object pc);
public void lockPersistent (Object pc, int level, long timeout);
public void lockPersistentAll (Object[] pcs);
public void lockPersistentAll (Object[] pcs, int level, long timeout);
public void lockPersistentAll (Collection pcs);
public void lockPersistentAll (Collection pcs, int level, long timeout);
```

And the next example:

// retrieve the lock level of an object

```
Stock stock = ...;
int level = KodoJDOHelper.getLockLevel (stock);
if (level == KodoJDOHelper.LOCK_WRITE) 
        PersistenceManager pm = ...;
        pm.currentTransaction ().setOptimistic (true);
        pm.currentTransaction ().begin ();
        // override default of not locking during an opt trans to lock stock object
        KodoPersistenceManager kpm = KodoJDOHelper.cast (pm);
        kpm.lockPersistent (stock, KodoPersistenceManager.LOCK_WRITE, -1);
        stock.setPrice (market.calculatePrice (stock));
        pm.currentTransaction ().commit ();
```

Answer (score 0):

What we end up doing in Kodo 3.4.0 is use CONN_RETAIN_PM (downcasting required):

```
try {
    pm = (KodoPersistenceManager)
        ((KodoPersistenceManagerFactory) kpmf).getPersistenceManager(false,
        KodoPersistenceManager.CONN_RETAIN_PM);
    Connection c = ((Connection)pm.getConnection());
    c.setTransactionIsolation(
        ISQLServerConnection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);

    // ... use pm with retained connection ...

} finally { // reset retained connection, e.g. if pooled
    if (pm != null) {
        Connection c = ((Connection)pm.getConnection());
        c.setTransactionIsolation(
            ISQLServerConnection.TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED);
    }
}
```